# Passing a singleton as argument in Scala

Tags: scala, singleton

I have this:

```
final case class MyClass(....) extends G with M[MyClass]

object MyObject extends GMC[MyClass] {....}

trait GMC[A <: G with M[A]] {....}

def f(gmc: GMC[G])

f(MyObject)
```

I get compiler error as:

> Type mismatch:
>   Required GMC[G], found MyObject.type

Is this wrong way of passing singleton?

Comment: Does `X` conforms to `T[A]` what is `A`? Which type did `X` used when inheriting `T`? Is `T` **covariant**, **contravariant** or **invariant**?

Comment: Please show us a complete, self-contained example, ie. the exact same code you use which reproduces the compiler error.

Comment: Where is `G` where is `M`? `f` doesn't compile-

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to updated question**

The problem lies with the definition of `f`. If you remove the call of `f` you get this error message:

> type arguments [G] do not conform to trait GMC's type parameter bounds [A <: G with M[A]]

In other words, you can't use a bare `G` as a type parameter for `GMC` where the type constraint for `GMC` is `G with M[A]`.

You need to constrain the type that `f` takes to match the definition of `GMC`:

```
def f[A <: G with M[A]](gmc: GMC[A]): Unit = ???
```

---

**Previous answer**

You need to specify the type parameter for `T` when you create the `object`:

```
object X extends T[A] {....}
```

If you make that change it will compile:

```
class A
trait T[A]
object X extends T[A] {}
def f(t: T[A]) = {}

f(X) // No error
```